# Find posts of user grouped by month, unixtime

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to find the number of posts for each user grouped by month.
I'm currently using INT(10) unsigned to store the date of posts.

what would be a super fast way to do this?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `media` (
  `pid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `class` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `date_class_changed` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `title` char(5) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_cs NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(1024) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `media` enum('image','video') CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `thumb` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(140) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(16) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `date` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `file` varchar(1024) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `hash` char(32) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `hashtag` text CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `meta` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `ip` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `kind` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`pid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `title` (`title`),
  KEY `hash` (`hash`),
  KEY `class_date` (`class`,`date_class_changed`),
  KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1022724 ;
```

This is the table, I'm talking about, I'd like to display the number of posts for each user for each mont, such as: september 2012, User X, N posts etc..

The query I'm using after the help from @fthiella is:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`), '%Y-%m') as YearMonth, username, COUNT(*) as Posts
FROM
  media
WHERE username = 'foobar'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

thanks God it's fast enough, now I'll try to optimize in case it's not using an index, but for now with almost 1M record is doing good. cheers.

Comment: Can you please give an example of the data you have and how you need it grouped

Comment: Please add table structure, example data and expeted result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`), '%Y-%m') as YearMonth,
    username,
    COUNT(*) as Posts
FROM
  media
GROUP BY
    DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`), '%Y-%m') as YearMonth,
    username
```

Comment: it throws an error: #1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATE_FORMAT'

Comment: SELECT DATE_FORMAT( FROM_UNIXTIME(  `date` ) ,  '%Y-%m' ) AS YearMonth, username, COUNT( * ) AS Posts
FROM media
GROUP BY 1 , username, this way it's working, now I'll make some tests to see if it's fast enough. thanks!